# Subgroup of free abelian group is free abelian via transfinite induction

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, set-theory, free-abelian-group

There are two common proofs of "if $G$ is free abelian then any subgroup $H$ is also free abelian" when $G$ has infinite rank, one using Zorn's lemma as in Lang's *Algebra*, one using a well ordering of the basis (in a neat way!) as in Kaplansky's *Set Theory and Metric Spaces*. I am wondering if the following "brute force attempt" can be made to work.

First assume $G$ is of finite rank $n$. Fix a basis of $G$, and express every element of $H$ as a column vector. Arrange them into an "$n$ by $H$" matrix, denoted $W=(w_{ij})$. Consider the ideal generated by the entries in the first row. It has to be of form $(a)$ where $a=k_1w_{1j_1}+\cdots k_sw_{1j_s}$, $k_i$ integers and $w_{1j_i}$ some of the entries in the first row (it could be the zero ideal). Now on the left of $W$ create an empty $n\times n$ matrix $W'$, and write the vector $w=k_1w_{j_1}+\cdots+k_sw_{j_s}$ in the first column, where $w_{j_i}=(w_{1j_i},\dots,w_{nj_i})^T$. By subtracting suitable multiples of $w$ from (the infinitely many) columns of $W$, we can make all entries in the first row of $W$ zero. Repeat this $n$ times, $W$ will become a zero matrix, and the nonzero columns in $W'$ (they increase in the row index of the first nonzero entry) would be a basis for $H$.

I guess this is essentially the "column operation" part of Smith normal form algorithm. Now what to do if $G$ is of infinite rank? Given a well-ordered basis $E$ for $G$, we create an $E$ by $H$ matrix and try to repeat the above procedure transfinitely; at the $\omega$-th step I want to take the "limit" of the matrix $W$; it's not clear that this is well defined, or even if it is, whether some column can now have infinitely many nonzero entries, so they don't represent elements in $H$ any more.

Comment: A basic difficulty with any approach along these lines is the following.  Suppose $G$ is free with basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $H$ is actually all of $G$.  You could then one-by-one pick as your basis vectors for $H$ $e_0-2e_1,e_1-3e_2,e_2-4e_3,\dots$, so that after each step your basis span all possibilities for the first $n$ rows.  After doing this for $\omega$ steps, though, you *don't* get a basis for all of $H$, nor can it even be extended to a basis for all of $H$ (the quotient by the subgroup it generates is not free).

Comment: The "brute force" transfinite induction approach that works is to at each step restrict your attention to only the elements of $H$ that vanish below the rows you have considered so far (so in the first step you would consider only the columns whose only nonzero entry is the first one, not all possible values in the first row).  This is in some sense doing the procedure you describe in reverse order (in the finite rank case, it is like starting at the end of your process instead of the beginning).  I don't have Kaplansky's book but I would expect this is basically the same as his proof.